# detached entity passed to persist: com.example.stockmgnt.model.Customer add a new Sale to list of sale that belongs to a customer that already exists

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am working on a stock management system using spring-boot.
I have five entities which are:

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long categoryId;
    private String categoryName;
    private String categoryDescription;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();
}




 @Entity
    public class Customer {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long customerId;
        private String customerName;
        private String customerPhoneNumber;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<Sale> sales = new HashSet<>();
    }

@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long itemId;
    private String itemName;
    private int itemUnitPrice;
    private int itemQuantity;
    private String itemDescription;
    private String itemImage;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Sale> sales = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Sale {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SaleId saleId = new SaleId();

    @ManyToOne
   @MapsId("customerId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("itemId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    private Item item;

    private LocalDate purchasedDate = LocalDate.now();
    private  int quantity;
    private float total;
}

@Embeddable
public class SaleId  implements Serializable {

    private Long customerId;
    private Long itemId;
}
```

A customer is relatesto a set of Sales.
Now , I want to create a new sale and relate it to a customer that already exists .

Add a new Sale to list of sale that belongs to a customer that already exists.

I implemented the following codes:

```
@Service
public class SaleService {


    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SaleRepository saleRepository;



    public Sale saveOrUpdateASale(Sale sale) {

        Customer cst = customerRepository.getCustomerByCustomerName(sale.getCustomer().getCustomerName());
        if (cst == null) {
            Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
            newCustomer.setCustomerName(sale.getCustomer().getCustomerName());
            newCustomer.setCustomerPhoneNumber(sale.getCustomer().getCustomerPhoneNumber());
            Item item = itemService.findItemById(sale.getItem().getItemId());
            Sale newSale = new Sale();
            newSale.setItem(item);
            newSale.setCustomer(newCustomer);
            newSale.setQuantity(sale.getQuantity());
            newSale.setTotal((sale.getQuantity() * sale.getItem().getItemUnitPrice()));
            newSale.setTotal((sale.getQuantity() * item.getItemUnitPrice()));

            if (item.getItemQuantity() <= 0)
                item.setItemQuantity(0);
            else if ((item.getItemQuantity() > 0))
                item.setItemQuantity(item.getItemQuantity() - sale.getQuantity());
            newCustomer.getSales().add(sale);
            saleRepository.save(newSale);
            customerRepository.save(newCustomer);
            itemRepository.save(item);
            return newSale;

        } else {

            Item item = sale.getItem();
            Sale newSale = new Sale();
            newSale.setItem(item);
            newSale.setCustomer(cst);
            newSale.setQuantity(sale.getQuantity());
            newSale.setTotal((sale.getQuantity() * sale.getItem().getItemUnitPrice()));
            newSale.setTotal((sale.getQuantity() * item.getItemUnitPrice()));
            if (item.getItemQuantity() <= 0)
                item.setItemQuantity(0);
            else if ((item.getItemQuantity() > 0))
                item.setItemQuantity(item.getItemQuantity() - sale.getQuantity());
            cst.getSales().add(sale);
            customerRepository.save(cst);
            saleRepository.save(newSale);
            itemRepository.save(item);
            return newSale;


        }
    }
```

and I got the following error:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.stockmgnt.model.Customer
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:427) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:543) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:637) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
```

I try many solutions and it did not work. I had a problem of Duplicated Id

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shared, it seems you didn't declared any `cascade` relationship between entities. You handled everything by yourself.

Let approach the problem the way you are trying (without declaring the cascade relationship)

Inside your `public Sale saveOrUpdateASale(Sale sale)` method, two cases separately. You can do it this way (I am asumming that, you do not update customer information inside the `saveOrUpdateASale` method.)

```java
public Sale saveOrUpdateASale(Sale sale) {
    if(sale.getSaleId() != null) {
        // Update your sale row here
        ... all your setting statements here before updating
    } else {
        // Create your sale row here
        ... all your setting statements here before creating
    }
    
    Customer customerProxy = customerRepository.getOne(sale.getCustomer().getCustomerId());
    sale.setCustomer(customerProxy);
    
    saleRepository.save(sale);
}
```

Comment: I follow your solution and I got a null pointer exception. What if I use cascade relationship between entities ?

Comment: }


    }
I am having a null excepition . The line is indicating where I want to save sale to customer list

Comment: cst.getSales().add(sale);                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.example.stockmgnt.service.SaleService.saveOrUpdateASale(SaleService.java:77) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.example.stockmgnt.controller.SaleController.addASale(SaleController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: From your code it seems you tried to add sale to the customer sales set. The method we are working we were updating / creating sales, why do we need to add sale object to the customer object. There is no need to do that reverse mapping. comment that line and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I want to  add sale to customer set . because a customer can make many sales. and at the end , I wish to see all the sales of the customer

Comment: When the sale is saved, this `sale` is already persisted. You need separate service method for fetching clients sales. If you fetch the client with all it's sales, then it will return the saved sales too.

Comment: please , so , I am Wrong ? Should I implement a different method ?

Comment: yes, the sole responsibility of this method to create or update the sale record. Write separate method for fetching the customer with sales.